# Extra toolbar installed on my Chrome after making an ISO image

Tags: google-chrome, usb-drive, viruses

I have a Lenovo X220.  It doesn't have a CD/DVD so I used your instructions of using "pendrive" USB installer.  Everything went fine and now I have the ISO image on my USB stock.

The only thing is that when I downloaded the USB installer a toolbar got installed on my Chrome and I don't know how to get rid of it.  I even deleted the USB installer and nothing.  Instructions appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type in `chrome://extensions` in your Google chrome and then click on the **trash** button next to the name of your toolbar. It should disappear immediatly.